# Is it possible to save an audio stream with pure JavaScript in the browser?

Tags: javascript, audio, ffmpeg, stream

I would like to make a webpage where visitors can save audio streams by clicking on links (not live streams, but links from a radio archive which uses streams), I want to do this without a server backend with pure JavaScript in the browser.
I read somewhere about the JavaScript port of FFMpeg, which can encode and save video / audio in the browser utilizing so called blobs. However download library is huge, as far as I remember 17 MB. In fact I would need only stream copying the audio streams, not a real encoding process. 
I usually use similar commands to save a programme:

```
ffmpeg -i http://stream.example.com/stream_20160518_0630.mp3 -c copy -t 3600 programme.mp3
```

I wonder, is it possible to compile a subset of FFMpeg into JavaScript which provides only the really needed stream copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var audio = new Audio();
var ms = new MediaSource();
var chunks = [];
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(ms);

ms.addEventListener('sourceopen', function(e) {
    var sourceBuffer = ms.addSourceBuffer('audio/mpeg');
    var stream;

    function pump(stream){
        return stream.read().then(data => {
            chunks.push(data.value)

            sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(data.value);
        })
    };

    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
        pump(stream);
    }, false);

    fetch("http://stream001.radio.hu:443/stream/20160606_090000_1.mp3")
        .then(res=>pump(stream = res.body.getReader()))

    audio.play()
}, false);

// stop the stream when you want and save all chunks that you have
stopBtn.onclick = function(){
    var blob = new Blob(chunks)
    console.log(blob)
    // Create object url, append to link, trigger click to download
    // or saveAs(blob, 'stream.mp3') need: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't work in this case, because the radio stream is endless. Somehow I have to interrupt the download at a point.

Comment: I see, well, then you have 2 other options. 1) Make a ajax call to that url and save chunks (**from a readable stream**) - create a blob from those chunks - then save it. 2) Use the awesome [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js) i just built - only going to work in Chrome v52 wish isen't even released yet

Comment: Thx, 1st method is working. Source code here http://pastebin.com/dfitDqBs
The only problem is: when I record audio from a server, which send a CORS header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *) it works perfectly. With servers which don't provide that header (moost of them) I get a Cross Origin Policy error. I have no clue how to resolve this.

Comment: That is not how i would recommend you to do that. See my updated answer how to get a readable stream